# Invariant violation: RN native module is not available

Tags: javascript, react-native, shared-libraries, native-module

I developed a library for React-Native using native modules in RN48, and is being manually linked to a project in RN59 and is working fine.  But when i upgraded the peer dependency of the library to RN62 and auto-linked (https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md) to the RN62 app (via podspec and pod install), the native module is not available.  Is there something I need to update in the library?

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnLKP.png)

Podfile:

```js
platform: ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

def add_flipper_pods!(versions = {})
versions['Flipper'] || = '~> 0.33.1'
versions['DoubleConversion'] || = '1.1.7'
versions['Flipper-Folly'] || = '~> 2.1'
versions['Flipper-Glog'] || = '0.3.6'
versions['Flipper-PeerTalk'] || = '~> 0.0.4'
versions['Flipper-RSocket'] || = '~> 1.0'
pod 'FlipperKit', versions['Flipper'],: configuration => 'Debug'
pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin', versions['Flipper'],: configuration => 'Debug'
pod 'FlipperKit/SKIOSNetworkPlugin', versions['Flipper'],: configuration => 'Debug'
pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin', versions['Flipper'],: configuration => 'Debug'
pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitReactPlugin', versions['Flipper'],: configuration => 'Debug'#
List all transitive dependencies
for FlipperKit pods# to avoid them being linked in Release builds
pod 'Flipper', versions['Flipper'],: configuration => 'Debug'
pod 'Flipper-DoubleConversion', versions['DoubleConversion'],: configuration => 'Debug'
pod 'Flipper-Folly', versions['Flipper-Folly'],: configuration => 'Debug'
pod 'Flipper-Glog', versions['Flipper-Glog'],: configuration => 'Debug'
pod 'Flipper-PeerTalk', versions['Flipper-PeerTalk'],: configuration => 'Debug'
pod 'Flipper-RSocket', versions['Flipper-RSocket'],: configuration => 'Debug'
pod 'FlipperKit/Core', versions['Flipper'],: configuration => 'Debug'
pod 'FlipperKit/CppBridge', versions['Flipper'],: configuration => 'Debug'
pod 'FlipperKit/FBCxxFollyDynamicConvert', versions['Flipper'],: configuration => 'Debug'
pod 'FlipperKit/FBDefines', versions['Flipper'],: configuration => 'Debug'
pod 'FlipperKit/FKPortForwarding', versions['Flipper'],: configuration => 'Debug'
pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitHighlightOverlay', versions['Flipper'],: configuration => 'Debug'
pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutTextSearchable', versions['Flipper'],: configuration => 'Debug'
pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin', versions['Flipper'],: configuration => 'Debug'
end

# Post Install processing
for Flipper
def flipper_post_install(installer)
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target |
  if target.name == 'YogaKit'
target.build_configurations.each do |config |
    config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1'
end
end
end
end

target 'MiniProject'
do# Pods
for
MiniProject
pod 'FBLazyVector',: path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
pod 'FBReactNativeSpec',: path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
pod 'RCTRequired',: path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
pod 'RCTTypeSafety',: path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
pod 'React',: path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
pod 'React-Core',: path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
pod 'React-CoreModules',: path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
pod 'React-Core/DevSupport',: path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
pod 'React-RCTActionSheet',: path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
pod 'React-RCTAnimation',: path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
pod 'React-RCTBlob',: path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
pod 'React-RCTImage',: path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
pod 'React-RCTLinking',: path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
pod 'React-RCTNetwork',: path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
pod 'React-RCTSettings',: path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
pod 'React-RCTText',: path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
pod 'React-RCTVibration',: path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket',: path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

pod 'React-cxxreact',: path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
pod 'React-jsi',: path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
pod 'React-jsiexecutor',: path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
pod 'React-jsinspector',: path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
pod 'ReactCommon/callinvoker',: path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core',: path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
pod 'Yoga',: path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga',: modular_headers => true

pod 'DoubleConversion',: podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
pod 'glog',: podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
pod 'Folly',: podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

pod 'react-native-video',: path => '../node_modules/react-native-video'

pod 'MyLibrary',: podspec => '../node_modules/my-library/MyLibrary.podspec'

use_native_modules!

  #Enables Flipper.##Note that
if you have use_frameworks!enabled, Flipper will not work and# you should disable these next few lines.
add_flipper_pods!
  post_install do |installer |
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you share podfile?

Comment: shared pod file